# DuplicateKeyException on empty table

Tags: sql, linq

I get a System.Data.Linq.DuplicateKeyException when adding an entity to an empty table.

```
grade g = new grade();
g.subject = dc.subjects.Single(x => x.subjectID == 5);
g.student = aStudent;
dc.grades.InsertOnSubmit(g);
```

I dropped the entire table itself and recreated it with no luck.
Grades is a join table with subjectID and studentID as foreign keys.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There might be problem with the primary key that is stored to be the next one. Try the following:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT("Grades", RESEED, 1)
```

You should also check the foreign key like this:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ("Subjects", NORESEED)
```